# How to process the file which have multiple json object and add new json object in the file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have file with mutiple json objects: `{"key1": "value1"}{"key2": "value2"}`. I want to update json file to `{"key1": "value1000"}` and add new entry: {"key3": "value3"}. I don't know how to add new json object to the file.

Updated JSON file will be like: `{}{}{}`. Please note JSON object is not comma separated file. This file has a collection of JSON objects, which is extracted from Google Cloud Storage.

```
def main_v2():
    data = ""
    with open('data.json', 'r') as outfile:
        for line_data in outfile:
            obj = json.loads(line_data)
            if len(obj["keys"]) > 1:
                keys = obj["keys"][1:  len(obj["keys"])]
                obj["keys"] = obj["keys"][0: 1]
                for key in keys:
                    temp = obj
                    temp['keys'] = key

            ##
            I don't know how to add new entry 
            ##  
     json.dump(data, 'jsonFile.data')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_v2()
```

Comment: What folks are trying to tell you is that the format of your file isn't valid JSON format. See the [JSON specification](http://json.org). How ever you are extracting the data from Google Cloud Storage isn't creating a valid JSON file.

Comment: Another way to solve this would be to somehow parse and convert the file you have into something that's legal JSON. If you could provide a more comprehensive sample of the existing file, then someone may be able to help you do that if you can't think of a way to do it yourself.

Comment: @martineau correct  Google Cloud Storage isn't creating a valid JSON file. However, I followed your suggestion and created valid JSON data. Thanks

Comment: Geeks: That's good to hear...and in that case, If you still have a question you need to either update what's in this one or ask another.

Comment: geeks: Actually converting the whole file into a valid JSON file will require reading the whole thing into memory first. However the code in your question expects a single JSON object on each line—which is actually a related format called [JSON Lines or JSONL](http://jsonlines.org) (also see the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Line-delimited_JSON) on it). Basically you need it to be in a format like this `{}\n{}\n{}\n` with newline characters between each object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you got wrong JSON:
This:

```
{"key1": "value1"}{"key2": "value2"}
```

Should be replaced with that:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

With this syntax you can use `json.loads()`. If you have some extra characters, or wrong JSON syntax, preprocess them before using `json.loads()`.
If you will do that adding new key, value pair to yours "dict" and updating is very simple with python:

```
import json

dict = json.loads('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}')
dict["key1"] = "value1000" #update existing value
dict["key3"] = "value3" #add new value
```

Comment: I have updated the question. This file has collection of json objects, which is extracted from Google Cloud Store

Comment: By collection you mean array of objects? Example: `[{"key1": "value1"},{"key2":"value2"}]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of json files.

1. A single json in the file - 
   {"key":"value","key":"value"}
2. An array of json objects - 
   [{"key":"value","key":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"},....]

So, first you need to validate your json. While loading the json file, `json.load()` takes care of it. The following code is for the first case

```
import json

data = json.load(open('data.json','r'))
data["key"] = "new_value" ## Update operation
data["new_key"] = "some_value" ## Insert new key-value pair
with open('data.json','w') as f:
     json.dump(data,f)
```

If the file contains json without commas, and if each json is on a new line, you can split the file data with `\n` and then join the strings with comma and save it as an array of json objects.

File format:

```
{"key1": "value1"}
{"key2": "value2"}
```

Code:

```
data = open('data.json','r').read().split("\n")
data = '[' + ','.join(data) + ']'
with open('data.json','w') as f:
     f.write(data)
```

Later process the file as a normal json file

Comment: Updated question, This file has a collection of JSON objects, which is extracted from Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: "If the file contains json without commas, and if each json is on a new line" => then it's a `jsonlines` file (http://jsonlines.org/) and there's already a lib to work with it (https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Oh, thanks @brunodesthuilliers. I didn't know about the library.